# Jtable and MVC, doesn't load to view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jtable

I'm new to MVC and Jquery. Trying to use jtable, but nothing happens when loading page.
This is my view.

```
<link href="~/scripts/jtable.2.4.0/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css" 
rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jtable.2.4.0/jquery.jtable.js">
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Hotels", FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div id="HotelsTable"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    //Prepare jtable plugin
    $('#HotelsTable').jtable({
        title: 'List of Hotels',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: '@Url.Action("HotelsList")'
        },
        fields: {          
            Hotel1: {
                title: 'Region',
                width: '10%'
            },
            Hotel2: {
                title: 'Hotel',
                list: false,
                width: '10%'
            },
            Hotel3: {
                title: 'Desde',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                width: '8%',
                list: false
            },
            Hotel4: {
                title: 'Hasta',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                width: '8%'
            },              
            Hotel5: {
                title: 'Comentarios',
                width: '8%',
            }
        }
    });
    //Load person list from server
    $('#HotelsTable').jtable('load');
});

</script>
}
</body>
</html>
```

This is my control:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult HotelsList()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Models.Models.HotelElem> hotels =      
            db.Database.Fetch<Models.Models.HotelElem>("SELECT * FROM Hotels");
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = hotels });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

While debugging it doesn't even go my HotelList() method. Need some help, what could it be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found solution! Maybe will be useful for someone.
Forgot to add

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

...)